# Power options change on restart (win8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1

Sometimes when I restart win8.1, the power plan changes. The 'sleep after' changes from an hour to never, and the lock screen after wakeup is turned on. I even created my own custom power plan, and its options change.

Comment: Is this your personal home computer, or a work computer?

Comment: Home laptop, which I use at work as well, but without any special workgroup login scripts.

Comment: As Techie007 hints, this might be due to Group Policy applied when  used at work. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/03/19/managing-power-with-group-policy-part-2-or-3.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc462804.aspx for how this is done.

Comment: All the options in the power management in the local group policy editor are set to not configured. Also, in my work they use only linux, and they treat Windows as blasphemy, so I don't think they would set any policies. And again, when I login to the network no scripts are ran, and I didn't configure anything special; the server requires only my mac address.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Win8.1 Power Options. I set it to High Performance. When I start my computer the next day, it is in the Balanced Power Option mode. Very Annoying Windows can not remember Power Options last set.

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).